# Chrome problem parsing Float from jquery css atribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, parsefloat

today i have a simple an understable problem for me . Next code:

```
alphavar = $('#frontcolour').css('opacity');
console.debug(alphavar+' '+parseFloat(alphavar));
```

It runs ok width Firefox and width Opera ( now all perfect :) ) , but chrome i dont know why it doesnt parse it ok : here the answer of the debug send for me (the second line of the code)

```
0,568966 0
```

The real value is 0.568966 , but chrome it seems to round it also being parseFloat not parseInt. Any idea?

Thx in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string has a comma instead of a period: "0,568966" instead of "0.568966".  Perhaps Firefox and Opera adjust the workings of `parseFloat` to deal with locale variation, but apparently Chrome does not.

Comment: Perfect , thx for all :D . This is the way: alphavar=alphavar.replace(',','.');

Answer (score 0):

use `.tofixed()` this function will return the number of digits are required after decimal points. Below example work for me in the Chrom and the Mozila as well

```
$("#total_amount").val(parseFloat($amt * $ticket).toFixed(2));
```